# When GFCI trips, metal enclosure becomes energized

Tags: receptacle

Sooooooo, the box is grounded to the receptacle. Also the outlet has no power coming out of it, though when I hit the test button the metal box becomes energized. But the outlet lets me test/reset at will so IDK whats going on haha.

Comment: Please replace the word "Soooooooo" with a thorough description of your installation.  **Describe it like we're *not* in the room looking at it with you**.

Comment: Can you post photos of the wiring inside the box, even?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that your metal box isn't grounded and you have a bad connection hitting the box. Boxes aren't grounded to outlets, outlets are connected to grounded boxes. Also, GFCI's don't need a ground to test and reset. Remove the outlet and verify that the box, is in fact, grounded, then check your connections.

Answer (score 2):

I did some testing... the ground coming into the box wasn't connected upstream in another junction box. Always test wires I guess before turning the electricity on.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you have a faulty GFCI receptacle that's creating a ground fault when testing.  I'd replace the receptacle and see if that clears things up.